# React.createElement doesn't work

Tags: reactjs

Could someone please help in figuring out why nothing is loading into my HTML page using React? The error that appears is a SyntaxError at line 15 (an unexpected token).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Venos</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
  <div id="react-app">

  </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var venosHeader = {
      React.createElement('div', {class: 'randomBody'},
        React.createElement('h2', {}, 'I love Cole...')
      )
    };
    ReactDOM.render(venosHeader, document.getElementById('react-app'));
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/react/0.14.0-rc1/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/react/0.14.0-rc1/react-dom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm still very new to React and I can't find a solution.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: {class: 'randomBody'} do you mean {className: 'randomBody'} ?

Answer (score 4):

```
var venosHeader = {
  React.createElement('div', {class: 'randomBody'},
    React.createElement('h2', {}, 'I love Cole...')
  )
};
```

This is not valid javascript.

Should be like this:

```
var venosHeader = React.createElement('div', {className: 'randomBody'},
    React.createElement('h2', {}, 'I love Cole...')
  );
```

Comment: also {className: 'randomBody'} instead of {class:'randomBody'} cause of React =)